# Why does Tomcat run without CATALINA_HOME?

Tags: tomcat

I have set up JAVA_HOME, PATH environmental variables. And NOTHING else

I know I also need to set up CATALINA_HOME

However, Tomcat EE works just fine without CATALINA_HOME

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tomcat startup script will try to detect the CATALINA_HOME if it is not defined as an environment variable.

This is defined in the `catalina.bat` or `catalina.sh` script

Linux:

```
# Only set CATALINA_HOME if not already set
[ -z "$CATALINA_HOME" ] && CATALINA_HOME=`cd "$PRGDIR/.." >/dev/null; pwd`
```

Windows:

```
if not "%CATALINA_HOME%" == "" goto gotHome
set "CATALINA_HOME=%CURRENT_DIR%"
```